# Flutter sqflite openDatabase method isn't defined

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I'm new to flutter development. I was trying to use sqflite to create a sqlite database in my mobile app.

```
import 'package:mcqlanka/src/util/constants.dart';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDatabase();
    return _db;
  }

  initDatabase() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, DB_NAME);
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return db;
  }


  _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE user (uid TEXT PRIMARY KEY, email TEXT, image TEXT)');
  }
}
```

But it always says openDatabase isn't defined in the class. I'm using sqflite: ^1.1.3. I tried with previous versions too. But I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to import `import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';`

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. I have imported import package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart' instead of package:sqflite/sqflite.dart
Now it works fine